# org.dozer.Mapper does not bind more

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, dozer, mapper

I'm using org.dozer.Mapper in my application. We migrated the db from mysql to oracle. Now the mapper does not work anymore. The only thing it does is bind ids between the model and the bean. 
has happened to someone such a thing? I do not know how to fix (besides the fact of eliminating Dozer)

Answer (score 0):

I would say you can remove Dozer, the best mapper code I know is the one you write for yourself.

Ok it's painfull but you will know exactly what happens during the mapping proces and be able to debug it.

I would recommend using something different like [Selma](http://xebia-france.github.io/selma/) because this library generates the mapping code so you can see what really and have compiler feedback when the mapping for some reason is not working.

The best you should do is looking at youre code beacause some refactoring have probably occured. I can also be a proxy issue depending on the ORM you are using.